# Different JSON output in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm creating the RSpec test files for a controller which only responds in JSON.
It's job is to serialize a Service object into a JSON object, which is working very well.

While I was creating the test for the controller, I noticed that it kept failing because the response JSON has different precision than the Rails generated one.

```
  describe "getting a service detail" do
    it "should succeed when a valid id is supplied" do
      service = create(:service, user: user)

      get( :show, id: service.id, format: :json )
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)

      result = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(result).to_not be_nil

      expect(result).to eq(service.api_json().to_json)
    end
  end
```

The method `api_json` is the same one used in the controller, therefore they should be equal. However, the float fields are getting different precisions:

```
"latitude":73.1379129975533,"longitude":170.75011612037 # Controller Response
"latitude":73.13791299755334,"longitude":170.75011612037048 # RSpec comparison
```

This is how the controller outputs the object:

```
  def show
    begin
      @service = @api_user.services.includes(task: :address).find(params[:id])

      respond_with @service do |format|
        format.json { render json: @service.api_json }
      end

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render nothing: true, status: 404
    end
  end
```

As you can see, nothing out of the ordinary: no precision set anywhere.

I've trying comparing the Response's Body directly also to no avail.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database stores floats with different precision - in your spec you're first creating a service assigning coordinates with some precision, then you're checking the response from your controller which is querying your DB for a given service. Your DB trims floats so you're getting a response with different precision.

I think you have 2 possible solutions:

1. Round your attributes when creating records using factories
2. Reload your service after creation (`service = create(:service, user: user).reload`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how could the DB be trimming the values if it's the same record? As noted in the code, I create the record first then I GET it via the controller and compare it against itself. I'll try your suggestion of reloading the model as soon as I can, though.

Comment: When you're creating an ActiveRecord object and save it in database, only primary key is reloaded (since it's assigned by DB in most cases). Your float attribute is stored in database with your database's float precision that might be lower than Ruby's float precision. That's why the value might be different when you reload your record.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem. I'm now looking into ActiveRecord validations to ensure the precision is the same in both Rails and the DB.